# Is there a way to get changes to a page in the MediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to show the content of all revisions to a page using the Mediawiki API?

Ie, could you query the [Barack Obama](http://wikipedia.org/en/barack_obama) and get all the modifications made?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the API docs? Were they unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`API:Properties#Revisions:_Parameters`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#Revisions%3a_Parameters)

[`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Barack%20Obama&rvprop=content|ids&rvlimit=10`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Barack%20Obama&rvprop=content|ids&rvlimit=10)

`rvlimit` up to 500.